# Defining Functor Instance for Tensor Type (Idris)

Tags: idris

I've been learning Idris recently, and decided I'd try to write a simple tensor library. I started by defining the type.

```
data Tensor : Vect n Nat -> Type -> Type
  Scalar : a -> Tensor [] a
  Dimension : Vect n (Tensor d a) -> Tensor (n::d) a
```

As you can see, the type `Tensor` is parameterized by a `Vect` of `Nat`s describing the tensor's dimensions, and a type, describing its contents. So far so good. Next I decided to try making the `Tensor` type a `Functor`.

```
instance Functor (Tensor d) where
  map f (Scalar x)    = f x
  map f (Dimension x) = map f x
```

And Idris gave me the following error.

```
Unifying `b` and `Tensor [] b` would lead to infinite type
```

Okay. From the error, I figured that maybe the issue was that the first pattern of `map` was too specific (i.e., would only accept scalars when the type declaration of map is such that it accepts any tensor). That seemed odd, but I figured I'd try rewriting it using a `with` statement.

```
dimensions : {d : Vect n Nat} -> Tensor d a -> Vect n Nat
dimensions {d} _ = d

instance Functor (Tensor d) where
  map f t with (dimensions t)
    map f (Scalar x)    | []     = f x
    map f (Dimension x) | (_::_) = map f x
```

But I got the same error. I have quite a bit of experience in Haskell, but I'm still not quite used to the lingo used in dependently typed programming in general and by Idris in particular, so any help understanding the error message would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: from Idris 0.10, the `instance` keyword is deprecated and should be simply left out).

The task is to apply the function to all elements in the `Scalar` constructors, but otherwise leave the structure unchanged. So, we need to map `Scalar` to `Scalar` and `Dimension` to `Dimension`, and since `Dimension` contains a vector of recursive occurrences, we should use `Vect`'s `map` to access them.

```
Functor (Tensor d) where
  map f (Scalar x)     = Scalar (f x)
  map f (Dimension xs) = Dimension (map (map f) xs)
```

So, in `map (map f) xs`, the first `map` is for mapping over `Vect`, and `map f` is the recursive call.